# Find those values 'a' which belongs to the Convex Hull

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Find those values of 'a' for which (1,a,1) belongs to the convex hull of

$$\{(0,0,0), (1,1,2),(2,4,-6), (1,3,8)\}$$

Give me hints as much as you can, I would like to understand the mindset rather than the mechanical way of solving it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can think about the extreme values $a$ for which $(1,a,1)$ lies in the convex combinations of the four given points (a closed set), since any intermediate values between the least and greatest such values of $a$ will again give such an included point (by convexity!).

Comment: @hardmath, looks like I misread the question, hard...

Comment: Okey, how would I proceed then @hardmath

Comment: @Nameless: At first glance it seems like more of a computation than I could do "by inspection", so there's an opportunity to figure the limiting "interval" for $a$, e.g. by simplex method(??), and post the Answer explaining how it was done.

Comment: Based on your tags it seems likely you are studying the simplex method/linear programming, and those techniques would lend themselves to solving for maximum and minimum feasible values of $a$.

Comment: I know how to solve a problem with simplex/LP problems too. But what I don´t understand is the way to solve it just by using coordinates.The course I am enrolled in is Optimization

Comment: The challenge here is probably to reformulate the problem as a linear program, then use the simplex method to find the endpoints $(1,a_\min,1)$ and $(1,a_\max,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to see that the plane $x=1$ cuts the tetrahedral solid generated by $\{(0,0,0),(1,1,2),(2,4,-6),(1,3,8)\}$ in a triangular section with vertices $(1,1,2),(1,2,-3),(1,3,8)$.

The plane $z=1$ then cuts this triangle along a line segment with an endpoint between the first and second of these vertices:

$$ \frac{4}{5} \cdot (1,1,2) + \frac{1}{5} \cdot (1,2,-3) = (1,\frac{6}{5},1) $$

and another endpoint between the second and third vertices:

$$ \frac{7}{11} \cdot (1,2,-3) + \frac{4}{11} \cdot (1,3,8) = (1,\frac{26}{11},1) $$

Thus "by inspection" the feasible interval for $a$ is:

$$  \frac{6}{5} \le a \le \frac{26}{11} $$

We could alternatively formulate the problem as a pair of linear programs, seeking the minimum (resp. maximum) value of $a$ such that:

$$ (1,a,1) = b\cdot (1,1,2) + c\cdot (2,4,-6) + d\cdot (1,3,8) $$

$$ b + c + d \le 1 $$

subject to $b,c,d \ge 0$ nonnegativity constraints.  The barycentric coordinates of $(1,a,1)$ with respect to vertices $(0,0,0),(1,1,2),(2,4,-6),(1,3,8)$ are $(1-b-c-d),b,c,d$ respectively.

Comment: The first step is something I don´t get. You say it is fairly easy to see, for me 3 dimension is not easy to see.

Comment: Visualize a tetrahedron, with four corners.  Two of the corners, $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,3,8)$, are in the plane $x=1$.  The other two corners, $(0,0,0)$ and $(2,4,-6)$, lie respectively below and above the plane $x=1$, and the edge that connects them passes intersects plane $x=1$ at its midpoint $(1,2,-3)$.  So the section of the "pyramid" (tetrahedron) sliced by $x=1$ is the triangle formed by the edge between $(1,1,2)$ and $(1,3,8)$ and the midpoint of the opposite edge $(1,2,-3)$.

Comment: Note that if one starts by intersecting the plane $z=1$ with the tetrahedron, the section cut is a quadrilateral and not so easy to picture.  That is, two of the four corners are above the plane and two are below (checking their $z$-coordinates).  It follows that the plane $z=1$ intersects four edges of the tetrahedron (and misses the other two edges).